# Squid as the https proxy not working

Tags: 18.04, proxy, squid

I'm trying to run squid proxy

I have tried to do as it said here :

> https://www.tecmint.com/install-squid-in-ubuntu/

but it isn't working.

This is my `squid.conf` : (all other lines are # )

```
# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt to list your (internal) IP networks from where browsing
# should be allowed
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12  # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16 # RFC1918 possible internal network
#acl localnet src fc00::/7       # RFC 4193 local private network range
#acl localnet src fe80::/10      # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines
acl localnet src 10.0.0.188 # David Computer
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

acl bad_urls dstdomain "/etc/squid/blacklisted_sites.acl"
acl good_url dstdomain "/etc/squid/good_sites.acl"
#http_access deny bad_url


# Deny requests to certain unsafe ports
http_access deny !Safe_ports

# Deny CONNECT to other than secure SSL ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

# Only allow cachemgr access from localhost
http_access allow localhost manager

http_access deny manager


#http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost

# And finally deny all other access to this proxy

#http_access deny all
http_access allow all

# Squid normally listens to port 3128
http_port 3128 transparent

acl bloclsite1 dstdomain yahoo.com
acl blocksite2 dstdomain www.rediff.com
#http_access deny www.yahoo.com
#http_access deny blocksite1

acl blockkeyword1 url_regex gmail
http_access deny bad_urls
http_access allow good_url
http_access deny blockkeyword1
```

all sites are getting ERR_TIMED_OUT

Could someone please explain why?
or maybe send a link to a simple working conf file ?

Comment: you forgot to include your squid.conf.

Comment: I have added now ,

Answer (score 2):

When you use squid as a http(s) proxy, you are doing MTM.
Sites with HSTS will not accept traffic between the proxy and the browsers to run over http.
If you want to use a https proxy, you need to create your own certificate and import it in the browser.
You can try this: https://elatov.github.io/2019/01/using-squid-to-proxy-ssl-sites/